# What is the right way to pass an array of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Is this the right way to pass an array of unique_ptrs if I want no copies?

In other words, I want everything that happens to x to impact arr in the caller.

```
void doWork( unique_ptr<Foo> x[] )
{
    // I want assignments to x to impact caller's arr
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Foo> arr[10];
    doWork( arr );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has no real problem, because arrays *decay* to pointers<sup>1</sup> when passed like this (by value). However, the following sure would be more C++:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo> > FooVec;   // dynamic size
typedef std::array<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, 10> FooArr; // fixed size (10)

void doWork( FooVec& x ) // or FooArr&
{
    // I want assignments to x to impact caller's arr
}

int main()
{
    FooVec vec(10); 
    FooArr arr;
    doWork( vec );
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In other words, it is equivalent to

```
void doWork( unique_ptr<Foo> *x )
```

To stop decay, pass by reference:

```
void doWork( unique_ptr<Foo> (&x)[10] )
```

Comment: And if it is fixed size, as the OP-code suggests, you could use `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, 10>`.

Comment: @Kleist: you missed my fast edits :) I even threw in _'C-array by ref'_

Comment: @sehe: tyvm - I have modified my code to better fit C++ paradigms, as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine for what you want (although I'm not sure it's the best design).

Because arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions and functions declared as taking arrays are adjusted to functions taking pointers, inside `doWork`, `x` is a pointer to the array of `unique_ptr<Foo>` `arr` declared in `main` and assignments to the members of the array will be visible in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a pointer instead.  Since you can't pass arrays to functions anyways, you code already does that -- the compiler will silently and confusingly turn any function parameters declared as arrays into pointers.